# Taking Derivative of a Matrix with functions in Maple. Want to leave functions as prime (f' or f'') and not evaluate

Tags: matrix, derivative, maple

I want to evaluate a matrix that has a function named alpha. When I take the derivative of alpha, I would like the result to give me an alpha'

Example: if I have `sin(alpha)` I want to get `cos(alpha)alpha'`  but throughout the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite unclear what you mean by stating that you have a "function" in Maple, of which you intend to take the derivative.

That could mean some expression depending upon a name such as `t`, with respect to which you intend on differentiating using Maple's `diff` command. And such an expression may be assigned to `alpha`, or it may contain the *function call* `alpha(t)`.

Or perhaps you wish to treat `alpha` as an operator name, and differentiate functionally with Maple's `D` command.

I shall make a guess as to what you meant.

```
restart;
Typesetting:-Suppress(alpha(t));
Typesetting:-Settings(prime=t):
Typesetting:-Settings(typesetprime=true):

M := Matrix([[ sin(alpha(t)), exp(p*alpha(t)) ]]);

map(diff, M, t);
```

If that's not the kind of thing that you're after then you should explain your purpose and needs in greater detail.

Your question's title mentions a desire to have something not "evaluate". What did you mean by that? Have you perhaps assigned something to the name `f`?

Comment: Thank you for answering and yes that is what I was searching for and sorry for my poor question. It was 12 hours into a hackathon and my brain was goop. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for answering. I found the solution after a lot of guess and checking and reading. Here is my code with my solution.

```
with(Typesetting)  : 
Settings(typesetdot = true);

a:= alpha(t)

Rna:= [ cos(alpha), -sin(alpha), 0; sin(alpha), cos(alpha), 0; 0, 0, 1 ]

b := beta(t)

Rab:= [ cos(beta), -sin(beta), 0; sin(beta), cos(beta), 0; 0, 0, 1 ]

Rnab:= Rna . Rab

Rnab:= map(diff, Rnab, t)
```

Sorry for the multiple answers, I am getting use to the website.